# Dynamic Layout of Data Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

After implementing data table, my modal is shown at the bottom of the page, As data table height is depends on the number of data.
I have tried this function but it doesn't work

```
"initComplete": function(){
                            $('#full-width').addClass('modal-overflow')
                            $('#full-width').css('margin','10%')
                        }
```

Comment: What's the question? What's the desired behavior/result, and how does it differ from the actual?

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken with css please try this.

```
"initComplete": function(){
                            $('#full-width').addClass('modal-overflow')
                            $('#full-width').css('margin-top','10% !important')
                        }
```

Comment: `!important` doesn't make much sense in `addClass`.

Comment: @CBroe yes you are right I edited the code. Now it's fine.

Comment: Can I pass parameters in function ?